# Modifying android.jar classes & replace it in Android device?

Tags: android, android-widget, dex

I downloaded the source code of Android SDK and modified the class android.widget.TextView.

Now, I am trying to figure out how I can replace the actual TextView running on my device with the modified one.

I found that the compiled classes reside in /system/framework on my phone.

Any pointers on how I can replace the appropriate jar & odex file?

Note: I also read in google groups that modifying bits-n-pieces of android will not work, we need to build entire source code.

Comment: Custom firmware=custom rom ! Xdadev is your friend .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I also read in google groups that modifying bits-n-pieces of android will not work, we need to build entire source code.

You don't have to rebuild the entire system if you just want to change a few lines here and there. Basically you need the phone where you can pull (and push!!) files with `adb`, and `apktool` or `smali`, depending on what are you planning to change, resources or code.

In case of resources (localization, translation):

1. Pull the framework-res.jar from the phone, use `apktool if framework-res.jar` to make it default framework for your future manipulations. You have to pull and import framework **every** time you use new phone or new version of Android.
2. Pull the file you want to change.
3. Use `apktool d` to decompile the file.
4. Make the changes you need.
5. Use `apktool b` to compile new file.
6. Zip and sign.
7. Push new file to the phone.

In case you want to change code, use `framework.jar` instead of `framework-res.jar` and `smali/backsmali` for compilation/decompilation of `.dex` files.

Also, it's always a good idea to make backup copies of the files you are about to change in case when something goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks lenik. I am going to try this approach today. Just one more question. When you said signing ? Does it mean I need to sign the Jar & dex file ? if so what kind of signing certificate should I use? I am sure my phone jars would have been signed using different cert. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: it works best, if you sign files using same certificate as your system. if you use AOSP builds the `test_keys` are supposed to work just fine. otherwise, if you change framework.jar, you might need to deodex all apps to remove the dependency and resign them all as well -- sorry, I am not sure about the details here.

Comment: Thanks again. What I did was Flash my Phone with custom ROM from Cyanogen Mod. Pull the required jars/apk from the installed ROM as they are unsigned ! Note: This is just for quick testing. I understand when I go live, I will need to sign with appropriate keys.